# Docker build state

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have an existential question about docker. Given this dockerfile:

```
FROM someImage
MAINTAINER abc
ENV something=somehow
RUN sh calculatePi.sh
ENV somethingElse=somehow2
```

"Calculate Pi" is a "continuous" program that never ends and needs to be ran on the background. It calculates all the digits of PI  (3.1415.....) and save it to a txt file.

My question:

1. Is this dockerfile even plausible?
2. If Yes, When I run a container based on this image, what is the saved state? In other words, if I open the txt file, what would I see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Docker builds an image, each instruction in the Dockerfile gets executed in an interim container, run from the preceding image layer. So if your `calculatePi.sh` ran endlessly then your image would never build - it would stick at the `RUN` instruction waiting for it to complete.

In practice, it's more likely that you'll max out disk or CPU resource and take down the machine if you tried to build it. Either way, you wouldn't get a completed image that you could run.

Comment: But if calculatePi runs in a background thread, it will not block the execution. Does it affect your answer or the answer will be the same?

Comment: If your script kicks off a new thread and **doesn't** wait for it to complete, then yes that does change. The `RUN` instruction will complete as soon as the script returns, and Docker will stop the container with the script still running in the background. I would expect the text file to be empty, but potentially it could write a couple of digits before it got stopped.

Answer (score 1):

No, that Dockerfile won't work.  `RUN` instructions need to complete before Docker can create an image from them.  Perhaps you want to make that a [`CMD` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) instead?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can write your docker file like this:

```
FROM someImage
MAINTAINER abc
ENV something=somehow
ENV somethingElse=somehow2
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
CMD ["calculatePi.sh"]
```

Then when you run this image

```
docker run -d thisImage
```

The script calculatePi.sh will run in your container as an App.